# MySQL Error 1146 (42S02): Table Doesn't Exist

Tags: mysql

I exported a database from a production server and I'm trying to import it into my local test environment. When I try to import it gives me the error below on multiple tables.

`ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'abc123' doesn't exist`

I have verified that the tables do exist in the production database and the sql file has the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

On the Production Database, the Collation is set to `latin1_swedish_ci` and each table Collation is set to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci' which I have replicated in the local database.

Production Database server: Server version: 5.7.34
Local Database server: Server version: 5.7.24

I have read through a lot of posts on SO and can't find a solution to this.

**EDIT:**
I was able to fix this problem by increasing the packet size in mysql.ini

Comment: Are you using foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, there are foreign keys in that table.

Comment: Maybe this happens when mysql is trying to create the table that contains the foreign keys before creating the referred table. I'd try to `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` when importing. It's just a guess cause this happend to me once.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updated.

Comment: @Junky answer you own question an accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by increasing `max_allowed_packet` to 64MB in the `mysql.ini`.